# dataSet.ReadXml(xmlPath) reads xml attributes into new tables

Tags: c#, .net, xml, dataset

Suppose i have the following xml :

```
<books>
    <book>
        <name>book 1</name>
        <author>aut 1</author>
        <length unit="cm">297</length>
    </book>
</books>
```

When i read this xml into a dataset using :

```
dataSet.ReadXml(xmlPath)
```

It will return a dataset with 2 tables: books and length. The table 'books' will contain 2 columns : 'name' and 'author'. The other table 'length' will contain all lengths.

I just want 1 table, 'books' with all 3 columns. The attribute 'unit' should just be ignored ... How do you do that ?

**Edit:** sorry, I solved it by just removing the text in the xml file :

```
        mainXML = mainXML.Replace(" unit=\"K\"", "");
```

Comment: Wow can't believe in that, perhaps you forgot include some part of XML/code?

Comment: Is the Dataset preconfigured with 2 tables (and a Relation) ?

Comment: This is the code for reading the dataset :
            DataSet dsMain = new DataSet();
            dsMain.ReadXml(xmlPath);
            return dsMain;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just read the xml file, removed the attributes and saved again. Not pretty, but it works ...

```
mainXML = mainXML.Replace(" unit=\"K\"", "");
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a typed `DataSet` in the designer that contains the relevant tables and fields. Then call `ReadXml` on an instance of that `DataSet`. This should work and also be more comfortable when accessing data.

Comment: That may work, but I cannot do that since it's a dynamic table... I don't get to specify the different fields of the table .. thanks though